# How can i get all the zip files in the folder based on the time they are created

Tags: shell, ubuntu, filesystems

for example i want the zip files that are created on 2/2/2023, how can i list all the zip files with date of creation as 2/2/2023.
thanks, any help would be much appreciated.

using

`stat -c %z file.zip`

we can find the date-time of a file but how can we do the reverse of it with the date we can list the files on linux os.

Comment: What does `a =s 2/2/2023` mean? Many filesystems do not store file creation time. You use `%z`. Do you actually want the last modified time?

Comment: @jhnc sorry it was a typo mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `stat` all zip files with date and name, and filter the desired date, e. g.:

```
stat -c'%z %n' *.zip | grep ^2023-02-02
```